# Pandas two dataframes looking up IP's in CIDR's and mapping inCIDR column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes. One(df1) with CIDR and a column that will always be one to enrich the second dataframe. The other dataframe(df2) has a list of ips.  I would like to possibly iterate the IP's through the the CIDR's in df1 and label df2 if it is in one.  I have read through the documentation for the libraries `ipaddress` and `netaddr` and have used both libraries in the past but I am having trouble figuring out how to use one in this situation.

If you get the range for cidr 13.64.0.0/11 you would get 13-64.0.0-13.95.255.255. 13.64.1.100 falls in that range

Dataframes:

```
df1
    CIDR           inCIDR
0   13.64.0.0/11   1
1   13.96.0.0/13   1
2   13.104.0.0/14  1
3   20.34.0.0/15   1
4   20.36.0.0/14   1
5   20.40.0.0/13   1
6   20.128.0.0/16  1
7   20.140.0.0/15  1
8   20.144.0.0/14  1
9   20.160.0.0/12  1
10  20.176.0.0/14  1
11  20.180.0.0/14  1
12  20.184.0.0/13  1
13  23.96.0.0/13   1
14  40.64.0.0/10   1
15  42.159.0.0/16  1

df2
    ipaddress
0   18.235.100.252   
1   13.64.1.100 
2   40.64.11.22  
3   184.84.243.59   
4   184.84.243.119  
5   20.180.22.12  
6   3.17.7.58  
7   34.233.202.21  
8   42.159.10.10
```

Desired output:

```
df2
    ipaddress        inCIDR
0   18.235.100.252   0  
1   13.64.1.100      1
2   40.64.11.22      1
3   184.84.243.59    0
4   184.84.243.119   0
5   20.180.22.12     1
6   3.17.7.58        0
7   34.233.202.21    0 
8   42.159.10.10     1
```

Possibly using map to assign the inCIDR like:

```
df2['inCIDR'] = df2['ipaddress'].map(df1.set_index('ipaddress')['inCIDR']).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: How do you map 13.64.0.0/11 to 13.64.1.100 ?

Comment: If you get the range for cidr 13.64.0.0/11 you would get 13-64.0.0-13.95.255.255.  13.64.1.100 falls in that range @Vaishali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to map values based on first two values in ipaddress

```
new_df = df1.copy()
new_df['CIDR'] = new_df['CIDR'].str.extract('(\d+.\d+).')

df2['inCIDR'] = df2['ipaddress'].str.extract('(\d+.\d+).')[0].map(new_df.set_index('CIDR')['inCIDR']).fillna(0).astype(int)

    ipaddress       inCIDR
0   18.235.100.252  0
1   13.64.1.100     1
2   40.64.11.22     1
3   184.84.243.59   0
4   184.84.243.119  0
5   20.180.22.12    1
6   3.17.7.58       0
7   34.233.202.21   0
8   42.159.10.10    1
```